# SoapUi generate soap for complextypes

Tags: soap, soapui

When generating a request using soapUi the tool will generate the soap request xml

But it will not expend complex types, instead it will just add:

```
<relations xsi:type="misc:ArrayOf_tns1_RequiredData" soapenc:arrayType="urn:RequiredData[]" xmlns:urn="urn:xeroxService"/>
```

Then its time consuming to understand how to expend this expression...

Is there any way around this? (using soapui 4.0.1 or 5.2.1)

Comment: Hope you might checked with schema or wsdl with your team or service provider. Have tried to generating request using any other tools which shows correctly? Do you mind trying with latest soapui?

Comment: tried latest soapui, same thing..

Comment: If possible, please provide a screen shot of request. By the way, have you selected "generate optional elements" check box while creating a new test request? Please see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you "generate optional elements" didn't make any difference..